# Check constraint in User Defined Type Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, check-constraints

I need to create a type that can hold only positive numbers that are between 8 and 13 characters in length. Best I was able to come up with is this, but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE1 AS OBJECT (
TYPE1 NUMBER (13)
) FINAL;


CREATE TABLE table1(
someNumber TYPE1
check ( someNumber between 11111111 and 9999999999999)
)
```

Looking for a way to, if possible, add constraint to UDT.

Comment: Why `11111111`? Why not `10000000`?

Comment: You are correct, it should be 10000000, but it's only an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the column name of the object

```
CREATE TABLE table1
  (
    someNumber TYPE1 
    CHECK (someNumber.TYPE1 BETWEEN 11111111 AND 9999999999999)
  );
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/live/DHZLD66331)

Comment: Is there any way to add some sort of a constraint to the UDT?
Also, you've solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing would be to code some validation in the type's constructor or methods. However, that wouldn't stop `someNumber` being set explicitly. 
There is no event to catch this that is equivalent to a table constraint or trigger, unless of course the object is for use in a table in which case you can define constraints on the table, but these will be independent of the type definition.